# What kind of hinges to use?

Tags: wooden-furniture, hinges

I have few panels on the wall (that hide electricity, internet, heating) that I wish to hide and came up with following sketch (sorry if it is not very clear, was using sketchup for the first time):
[image]

The problem is, that my carpenter says that I need at least 8cm gap for hinges to mount and I with to keep that gap closer to 2cm.
Is there any kind of hinges, that would allow to make gap between wall and doors as small as possible?

*Update*:
Lots of good questions in the comments, some additional info:

- the wall is drywall, hence I would prefer not to attach hinges directly to it, unless you'll say that it is better idea than attaching hinges to MDF board strips
- would like to avoid large vertical gaps between panels too
- bifold/sliding is an option too, if there's no visible from the front additional details for it (the width of both doors is ~120cm, height is also 120cm, so there's some weight, I guess there should be some kind of supporting rail or smth to handle that)
- hopefully I'll need to open this door once/twice a year, in other words very occasionally.

Comment: Are you sure it not mm instead of cm?  2 cm about the width of a thumb, no doors I know have is even that far of a gap.

Comment: Have you considered using a bi-fold or sliding bypass doors instead?  Would you ever have a need to have all doors open at once or could you live with having to slide one in front of the other?

Comment: gap? are you asking how to reduce the depth (front to back) of your cabinet?  I'm assuming these are cabinet hinges, can you cut holes in the wall to fit the tail of the hinge? do you actually need hinges?  maybe just make a cover that attaches to the wall with french cleats.

Comment: take a trip to your nearest big box hardware store ... they may have various hinges in a working display

Comment: If you are intending to hide the electrical circuit breaker panel you may be in a violation of the electrical code.

Comment: @crip659 - 2cm, because the hinge needs to be attached to something and that something probably is should not be wall, but wooden panel strip, also the panels I wish to hide are ~5mm extruding from the wall.

Comment: @ChrisO - I will need to open both doors rarely, as couple of panels I'm trying to hide are in the middle.

Comment: @MichaelKaras - quite often this electricity panel is in the closet (and was so in original interior design), so I'm not sure, I'll try to read about it.

Answer (score 4):

A piano hinge requires nearly no gap at all. It may or may not suit your purpose but certainly it provides the tightest clearance between two perpendicular hinged surfaces.

Comment: Piano hinge is interesting solution, but if I understand correctly it has one drawback - you would need to make gap between the panels, as the rotating edge does not move, so you need clearance for the thickness of the panel?

Answer (score 3):

Soss or [Tambee](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HMK9YLX) hinges will only need a 1/16" gap and are not visible when the door is closed
[[image: pic 1][image]

Comment: I'll try to see if such kind can be used with 18/20mm MDF board too, thanks.

Comment: MDF may not have the holding power needed for the screws with any type of hinge unless it may be cross pinned with wood dowels to intersect with the screws. MDF Is also really heavy, you will need enough to handle the weight.

Comment: Just need to use the right type of screws for MDF. Screws with very coarse threads. Of course, the MDF _still_ won't screws as well as just about any other wood-like product, but for a couple of uses a year, it would probably last _long enough_.

Answer (score 1):

Used @jsotola's suggestion and went to specialized store, but the guy there was really lousy, and had nothing to offer, nevertheless I had a chance to see some brand names, so I went back home and browsed in internet through their collections.

Blum had compact series, but those seem to be available in US only: https://www.blum.com/us/en/products/hingesystems/compact-blumotion/programme/

Hettich had what I needed and that was available right away in stock:
https://www.demos-trade.eu/hettich-9072548-optimat-plus-tb42-16/

Comment: "simonswerk tectus" is also nice